# Can a recursive CTE search from the bottom up?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Given the following table in PostgreSQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE territories 
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar NOT NULL,
    containing_id int
);

CREATE INDEX container_id_index ON territories (containing_id);
```

And this sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO territories (id, name, containing_id)
VALUES
    (1, 'Earth', NULL),
    (2, 'North America', 1),
    (3, 'South America', 1),
    (4, 'Africa', 1),
    (5, 'Asia', 1),
    (6, 'United States', 2),
    (7, 'Canada', 2),
    (8, 'Mexico', 2),
    (10, 'Georgia', 6),
    (11, 'Atlanta', 10),
    (12, 'Nigeria', 4),
    (13, 'Abuja', 12),
    (14, 'Chile', 3),
    (15, 'Santiago', 14),
    (16, 'Ontario', 7),
    (17, 'Toronto', 16),
    (19, 'Cambodia', 5),
    (20, 'Phnom Penh', 19);
```

I can write a "top-down" recursive CTE to list all locales under a given starting point:

```sql
-- top-down query
WITH RECURSIVE superterritories AS 
(
    SELECT
        id,
        containing_id,
        name,
        NULL::varchar AS superterritory_name
    FROM
        territories
    WHERE
        name = 'Earth'
    UNION
    SELECT
        t.id,
        t.containing_id,
        t.name,
        sup.name AS superterritory_name
    FROM
        territories t
    INNER JOIN 
        superterritories sup ON sup.id = t.containing_id
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    superterritories;
```

This outputs

```
 id | containing_id |     name      | superterritory_name
----+---------------+---------------+---------------------
  1 |        [NULL] | Earth         | [NULL]
  2 |             1 | North America | Earth
  3 |             1 | South America | Earth
  4 |             1 | Africa        | Earth
  5 |             1 | Asia          | Earth
  6 |             2 | United States | North America
  7 |             2 | Canada        | North America
  8 |             2 | Mexico        | North America
 12 |             4 | Nigeria       | Africa
 14 |             3 | Chile         | South America
 19 |             5 | Cambodia      | Asia
 10 |             6 | Georgia       | United States
 13 |            12 | Abuja         | Nigeria
 15 |            14 | Santiago      | Chile
 16 |             7 | Ontario       | Canada
 20 |            19 | Phnom Penh    | Cambodia
 11 |            10 | Atlanta       | Georgia
 17 |            16 | Toronto       | Ontario
(18 rows)
```

With `WHERE name = 'United States'`, it outputs:

```
 id | containing_id |     name      | superterritory_name
----+---------------+---------------+---------------------
  6 |             2 | United States | [NULL]
 10 |             6 | Georgia       | United States
 11 |            10 | Atlanta       | Georgia
```

But is it possible to write a "bottom-up" recursive CTE, to list all locales into which a particular locale falls?

Comment: For direct parent/child, why bother with a recursive CTE while a simple left join would do the job?

Comment: The fact that I use `WHERE name = 'Earth'` maybe obscures the fact that this query doesn't have to do every row, just the rows descended from the one selected (which in this case, being the top level, is the same thing). Added an example starting at the country level.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes - by swapping the columns in the inner join

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229520/8343) clued me in that the key is to swap the columns in the `INNER JOIN`. Some renames help to clarify things, too.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE subterritories AS (
    -- Non-recursive query term. Evaluated once.
    SELECT
        id,
        containing_id,
        name,
        NULL::text AS subterritory_name
    FROM
        territories
    WHERE
        name = 'Atlanta'
    UNION
    -- Recursive query term. Evaluated repeatedly.
    SELECT
        t.id,
        t.containing_id,
        t.name,
        sub.name
    FROM
        territories t
        INNER JOIN subterritories sub ON sub.containing_id = t.id
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    subterritories;
```

This outputs:

```
 id | containing_id |     name      | subterritory_name
----+---------------+---------------+-------------------
 11 |            10 | Atlanta       | [NULL]
 10 |             6 | Georgia       | Atlanta
  6 |             2 | United States | Georgia
  2 |             1 | North America | United States
  1 |        [NULL] | Earth         | North America
```

With `WHERE name = 'Nigeria'` (starting at the country rather than city level just to demo that) it outputs:

```
 id | containing_id |  name   | subterritory_name
----+---------------+---------+-------------------
 12 |             4 | Nigeria | [NULL]
  4 |             1 | Africa  | Nigeria
  1 |        [NULL] | Earth   | Africa
```

Comment: The fun starts when you want not only the direct parent, but rather the entire path (Toronto -> Ontario -> Canada -> N.A -> Earth)

Comment: @JGH how is that different from what I showed here - Atlanta up to Earth?

Comment: I meant the entire path in a single row

Comment: I can get that putting the above in a CTE and doing `SELECT array_agg(cte.name) FROM cte GROUP BY true;`

Comment: Fair enough. I have often seen the recursive CTE doing the aggregation within the CTE, so one can query it for multiple inputs at once (ex: `select * from ... where name in ('toronto','lagos','paris');`), and in these case going upward in the CTE leads to surprising (i.e. partial) results (`Toronto -> Ontario`, `Toronto -> Ontario -> Canada` etc)